# Trying to write a program that simulates a craps using specific rules

Tags: java

this is the question:

In the game of craps, a pass line bet proceeds as follows: Two six-sided dice are rolled; the first roll of the dice in a craps round is called the " come out roll." A come out roll of 7 or 11 automatically wins, and a come out roll of 2,3 or 12 automatically loses. If 4,5,6,8,9 or 10 is rolled on the come out roll, that number becomes "the point". the player keeps rolling the dice until either 7 or the point is rolled. If the point is rolled first, then the player wins the bet. if a 7 is rolled first, then the player loses

Write a program that simulates a craps using these rules without human input. Instead of asking for a wager, the program should calculate whether the player would win or lose. the programs should simulate rolling the two dice and calculate the sum. Add a loop so that program plays several times. Add counters that count how many times the player wins, and how many times the player loses. at the end of playing the games several times, computer the probability of wining ( wins/sins+losses)) and output the value

and this is what I did so far

```
  import java.util.Scanner;

    public class partb1
 {

    public static void main(String[] args)
 {

int side1=1, side2=1 , roll=1, lose=0, win=0, point=0, answer;
     Double winprob, loseprob;

side1= 1+(int)(Math.random() *6);

     side2= 1+(int)(Math.random() *6);

     Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);

     do
     {
     roll = side1+side2;


     if ( roll == 7 || roll == 11)
     {
       System.out.println(" Come out wins");
     winprob = win + 1;

     }
     else if ( roll ==2 || roll ==3 || roll ==12)
     {
       System.out.println(" Come out loses ");
      loseprob = lose +1;

     }

     else
     {
          side1= 1+(int)(Math.random() *6);
     side2= 1+(int)(Math.random() *6);
     point = roll;
   roll = side1+side2;

       System.out.println("The point");
       System.out.println("You won the bet");
       winprob = win + 1;
   while(roll != point || roll!= 7);
        side1= 1+(int)(Math.random() *6);
     side2= 1+(int)(Math.random() *6);
    roll = side1+side2;

     }



     if( roll ==7)

     {
       System.out.println("You lost the bet");
     answer = kb.nextInt();
     } 
     else if (roll == point) {
        System.out.println(win);
    }

  while(true)
       {
    System.out.println(" Do you want to play again? 0 for No, any number for Yes ");

                     if (answer ==0)
                     {
                       break;
                     }

                     winprob = (40/(40+60));
                     System.out.println(" The probability of wining is " + winprob);

                     loseprob = (40/(40-60));
                     System.out.println(" The probability of losing is " + loseprob);




        }
      }
      }
       }
```

I keep getting this error

```
    1 error found:
    File: H:\assignment 3\partb1.java  [line: 84]
    Error: Syntax error, insert "while ( Expression ) ;" to complete DoStatement
```

I'm not sure whether I missed something or did something wrong?
Any clue?

Comment: `wins/sins+losses` So does `sins` represent how many times the user swore when they crapped-out?

Comment: It is just the probability of wining and losing, I'll need to include both of them in the program

Answer (score 0):

`answer` is an `ìnt` not a `boolean` so can't appear on its own in a `while` statement expression, but since you explicitly `break` out of the loop you can do:

```
while (true) {
```

Comment: Thanks ! The first error was resolved, the second issue came because the break is out of the loop

Answer (score 0):

As a matter of clean programming, I suggest not creating stuff like

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // do everything here
}
```

Apply the concept of encapsulation to your programming and break down your code into reusable chunks. You'll find it MUCH easier to debug your code and other programmers will love you for it.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple errors in your code, and whilst we are happy to help you with your homework ;) it would make it easier if you first aligned the code properly in a proper IDE so that you can see all the easy errors - such as where curly braces are mismatched or missing.

May I suggest downloading IntelliJ IDEA (or equivalent), loading up your java program, and hitting CRTL-ALT-L to "reformat" the code. This will make it more readable, and easier to fix.

Plus, the IDE can also help you track down errors (look for the "red" ink!)

For example there is an extra semicolon here, and the reformatting of the code makes it obvious:

```
        } else if (roll == point) ;
        System.out.println(win);
```

should maybe be

```
        } else if (roll == point) {
            System.out.println(win);
        }
```

Once you have the syntax figured out, why not use some methods and fields in your class? For example you could have methods `win()` and `lose()` and fields that are appropriate.

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you very much ! I will download the program as soon as I get home. Meanwhile, after editing that problem I got these errors:3 errors found:
File: E:\assignment 3\partb1.java  [line: 83]
Error: while expected
File: E:\assignment 3\partb1.java  [line: 85]
Error: illegal start of expression
File: E:\assignment 3\partb1.java  [line: 85]
Error: reached end of file while parsing

Comment: No worries Ryan, happy to help. Can you edit and post the code you have now? You need to figure how each game of craps 'ends' (win? lose? -> `break;` out of the do/while loop?) and how / where to process the user input with `answer = kb.nextInt()` correctly.

Comment: I edited the post.  So do I need to break after every lose or win?

Comment: Yes, that's the easiest way to break out of the innermost loop which represents one game. Then you need an outer loop, e.g. `do`... `while (answer == 1)` to play multiple games. At the moment the logic is not correct and some your curly brackets are misplaced - have a look when you reformat the code and you'll easily see where.

Comment: I tried to download IntelliJ IDEA, but I couldn't import anything for some reason. I'm using Dr.Java. I did some changes and I updated the post

Comment: Ryan, your error here is because your `do { } while (...)` loop is not ended correctly. Plus there are other errors, but you still need to reformat the code (manually in an editor if you have to) to see where. And you need two nested loops here (outer loop to keep playing games if user wants to, and an inner loop to complete rolling until one game is complete). Plus you might benefit from using methods, rather than one big peace of code. For example methods like `playOneGame()`, `win()` and `lose()` could help.